# Setting a prop of a child component inside a parent component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a paged table and I want to be able to customize my row output.

Which looks like.

```
    var PagedTable = React.createClass({


     propTypes:{
      'table_headers' : React.PropTypes.array,
      'table_rows' : React.PropTypes.array
     },
     getInitialState: function(){
      return{
       pageSize: 10,
       currentPage: 1
      }
     },
     componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      this.setState({
       currentPage: 1
      })
     },
     getPage: function(){
      var start = this.state.pageSize * (this.state.currentPage - 1);
      var end = start + this.state.pageSize;

      return{
       currentPage: this.state.currentPage,
       table_rows: this.props.table_rows.slice(start, end),
       numPages: this.getNumPages(),
       handleClick: function(pageNum) {
        return function() {
         this.handlePageChange(pageNum)
        }.bind(this)
       }.bind(this)
      } 
     },
     getNumPages: function() {
      var numPages = Math.floor(this.props.table_rows.length / this.state.pageSize);
      if (this.props.table_rows.length % this.state.pageSize > 0){
       numPages++
      }
      return numPages   
     },
     handlePageChange: function(pageNum) {
      this.setState({currentPage: pageNum})
     },
     render:function(){
      var page = this.getPage();
      var topics = page.table_rows.map(function(row) {
       return <IncompleteRow row={row}/>
      });
      return <div>
        <table className="table table-hover table-primary table-bordered colm-freeze">
          <PagedRowHeader header_row={this.props.table_headers}/>
          {topics}
        </table>
      </div>
     }
    });
```

The above code is modified but highly based off of: [this](http://bl.ocks.org/insin/8320083).

```
    <PagedTable>
      <IncompleteRow/>
    </PagedTable>
```

or like

```
    <PagedTable>
      <CompletedRow/>
    </PagedTable>
```

As you can see. Right now I am setting incomplete row in the render method. But I want to make this component extensible. Which means I want to be able to render different kinds of rows.

The problem is that to know what rows to render I need to be in the PagedTable class as it knows which rows should currently be displayed. So my PagedTable needs to be aware of what type of row it wants to render.

I've tried playing around with this.props.children but I'm getting stuck on how to set the child's proptype from the parent component.

Comment: How do you know which type of row you want rendered? Is there some property on the `row` items?

Comment: @jmarr to answer your question I don't! It entirely depends where I want to use it in the app. I want this to be a general purpose paged table. Right now I know which rows I want to use because I'm only using it on one page but I want to be able to use it many places without needing to create a new paged table class everytime. I just want to feed it rows.

Comment: jmar777 and @cwbutler both have answers that work (Thank you!). From my angle cwbutler's seems to me to be more flexible (I want to be able to use the paged row component across the app) while jmarr777 seems to be better for performance. Thoughts on best style?

Comment: honestly there shouldn't be much of a performance difference between the two. I would just go with whichever one works the best for your needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting stuck on how to set the child's prototype from the parent component.

I use [React.Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) and [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to map the child elements with correct properties from the parent class.

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    someProperty: this.props.someProperty
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish, but couldn't you do something like:

```
var topics = page.table_rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.someFlag ? <CompletedRow row={row}/> : <IncompleteRow row={row}/>;
});
```