# How to get position of element React | Redux (.getBoundingClientRect() + .getWrappedInstance())

Tags: reactjs, redux, getboundingclientrect

I am trying to find a position of a component rendered with React. 
I am using redux, so I had to modify the connect function to:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps,null,{ withRef: true })(MyComponent);
```

Now I am getting a component back when I call:

```
class OneColumn extends Component { 
    componentDidMount(){

        var input = this.refs.myComponentsRef.getWrappedInstance();

        console.log(input); // Outputs > TheComponentIWant {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _reactInternalInstance: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper…}

        var inputRect = input.getBoundingClientRect(); 
        console.log(inputRect); // Outputs error: Uncaught TypeError: input.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    }
//...
}
```

So I can get the component, however I cannot then get the boundingClientRect.

Anything I am overlooking?

Please help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an alternate solution that circumvents this problem: [This post describes and refers to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264102/get-dimensions-and-position-of-an-element-using-pure-javascript/43281870)

Basically when the components starts rendering the components give a callback function where you store the positions of those components.